# how to disable automatic logged out feature in web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

how to disable automatic logged out feature in web.config....

Comment: Are you referring to session timeout?  You really need to provide more information.  What authentication type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, as when the session expires, it will automatically logout. But there is an option in increase the session timeout value in the web.config file.

```
<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
```